# Heap allocated to elasticsearch node in an m4.large.elasticsearch instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elasticsearch

The jvm node stats `<endpoint>/_nodes/stats/jvm` in elasticsearch suggests that, in the case of an `m4.large.elasticsearch` instance type, the allocated heap size in 4Gb whereas the capacity of the instance type in 8Gb. Is it possible to increase this allocated heap for the elasticsearch node running on the instance.

Comment: You should read this: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html#_give_less_than_half_your_memory_to_lucene

Answer (score 0):

I dont see that as an option or Advanced option in AWS ES CLI [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-createupdatedomains.html) . AWS calculates that by instance type ( Min(Approx 50% memory , ~ [32 GB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-limits.html))).